# How to use req() with shinyjs toggle functions to enable/disable elements?

Tags: shiny, shinyjs

The app below will properly disable the button if at least 1 character is entered, and then enable it with 6 or more. The button is enabled when no characters are given though, because req(input$some_text) returns a silent error.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
   useShinyjs(),
     textInput("some_text", "Write at least 5 characters to enable button",
               value = ""),
     actionButton("button", "A Button")
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  first_step <- reactive({
    req(input$some_text)
    stringr::str_count(input$some_text, "[0-9]") > 5
  })

  observe({
    toggleState("button", condition = first_step())
  })
}
```

I understand toggle() has nothing to work with when there is no input.
In such a scenario, should an if-clause always be used instead?

```
  first_step <- reactive({
    if(input$some_text > 0){
        stringr::str_count(input$some_text, "[0-9]") > 5
    } else FALSE
  })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, note that I added `disable` at the start

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  textInput("some_text", "Write at least 5 characters (numeric) to enable button",value = ""),
  actionButton("button", "A Button")
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  first_step <- eventReactive(input$some_text,{
    disable("button")
    req(input$some_text)
    stringr::str_count(input$some_text, "[0-9]") >= 5
  })

  observeEvent(first_step(),{
    toggleState("button", condition = first_step())
  })
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

[image]

Comment: well you did answer my question, but now I realize my example was too simple, in comparison to my actual problem. What I actually need to do is the case where first_step() is the result of nchar(input$some_text) **<** 5 but the button is still disabled whenever the field has no text. The solution above will always return "TRUE", even when the user hasn't entered text.